# Using build_#{association} on an existing collection of model.others where model has_many others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, simple-form, cocoon-gem

The title is obviously confusing so let me get down to it.

```
class Resume < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :references
end

class Reference < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :phone
end

class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

So I'm using cocoon and to have the `simple_fields_for :phone` populated I need to run build_phone on every reference object created.

Similarly I had resume has_one basic_info has_one phone.
And I was able to build it like so

```
@resume.build_basic_info
@resume.basic_info.build_phone
```

But in this case I have:

```
@resume.references.build
@resume.references.first.build_phone
```

<strike>Give me the error `unknown attribute: reference_id`.</strike>

So how do I build the phone association for references in the cocoon form and have it built on every instantiation of a new reference in cocoon?

Edit: I didn't have `reference_id` in phone. And thanks to @vee I have a much better way of handling existing models. So the code works now.

Still need to figure out how to run build_phone on every new call to `link_to_add_association` in cocoon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a block when you build references as:

```
@resume.references.build do |r| 
  r.build_phone
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a great solution to my first problem.